# Can't mock Vue composable function with vitest

Tags: unit-testing, vuejs2, mocking, nuxt.js, vitest

In a Vue/Nuxt project, to separate the all the business logic and data, I have created a new function with the help of Vue composition api.

The custom composable function will help me to do some validation, and control the UI view based on the validation result.

Here is my composable function:

```
// ./composables/useFormData.ts


import { ref, Ref } from 'vue';

interface IUser {
    name: string;
    email: string;
}
export function useFormData(user: IUser) {
    const btnColor: Ref<string> = ref('gray');
    const enableBtn: Ref<boolean> = ref(false);
    const errors: Ref<string[]> = ref([]);

    function validationOk(): boolean {
        let errMsg = [];
        if(!user.name) {
            errMsg.push("User name is required。\n");
        }
        if(!user.email) {
            errMsg.push("Email is required. \n");
        }
        if(errMsg.length) {
            errors.value = [...errMsg]
        }
        return errMsg.length == 0 ? true : false;
    }

    function enableConfirmButton(): void {
        if(!validationOk()) return; // do nothing
        // update state value
        enableBtn.value = true;
        btnColor.value = 'green'; 
    }
    return {
        errors,
        btnColor,
        enableBtn,
        validationOk,
        enableConfirmButton,
    }
}
```

The custom vue composable function is used by a vue component. Here is the sample of my vue code:

```
// ./pages/form.vue

<template>
    <div>
    <h1>Custom Form</h1>
    </div>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import { ref, Ref, getCurrentInstance, onMounted } from 'vue';
import {useFormData} from '../composables/useFormValidation';
interface IUser {
        name: string;
        email: string;
    }
// dummy data
const user: Ref<IUser> = ref(
    {
        name: 'John Doe',
        email: 'test1@gmail.com',
    }
);

const {
    btnColor,
    enableBtn,
    enableConfirmButton,
    errors,
    validationOk
} = useFormData(user.value);

// ... do something

</script>
```

I want to do unit testing for the custom composable function, in my case useFormData.ts. To check all the possible cases, I want to mock the validationOk function.

To mock the composable function, I have followed several approaches, but nothing seems working

### First approach:

Importing the composable function like this

```
import {useFormData} from '../../composables/useFormValidation';
import { config } from '@vue/test-utils';
import { beforeEach, describe, expect, it, vi } from 'vitest';

vi.mock('../../composables/useFormValidation.ts', async () => {
    const actual : any = await vi.importActual("../../composables/useFormValidation.ts")
    return {
        ...actual,
        validationOk: vi.fn().mockReturnValue(true) // should be mocked, but no result
        // validationOk: vi.fn(() => true) // should be mocked, but no result
    }
})

describe('useFormData', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
        vi.clearAllMocks();
        vi.resetAllMocks();
    });
  
    test('mock validationOk function to forcefully return true', () => {
    const { btnColor, enableBtn, enableConfirmButton, validationOk } = useFormData({ name: '', email: ''});
    
    expect(validationOk()).toBe(true); // I want the validationOk() to be false
    });
});
```

### Second Approach:

```
describe('useFormData', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
        vi.clearAllMocks();
        vi.resetAllMocks();
    });

    it('allow mocking inner function', () => {
        const validationOkMock = vi.fn(() => {
            return false; //set to false,
        });
        vi.stubGlobal('validationOk', validationOkMock);
        const { btnColor, enableBtn, enableConfirmButton, validationOk } = useFormData({ name: 'aa', email: 'ss@ss.com'});

        expect(validationOk()).toBe(false);
    })
})
```

For both of the above approaches, the validationOk() method can not be mocked. I think it would be very great if we could do unit testing and mocking to composable function.

I'm new to vue / vitest.

Comment: I have the same problem and also tried various approaches but did not find a solution.

Comment: Same for me, I just spent hours trying to find a solution. Nothing worked. :(